# Pentaho not starting because it tries bind to port 9092 already used by itself

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to start `Pentaho` server on Debian Jessie.

Pentaho crap itself by showing the following error:

```
15:55:24,198 WARN  [PentahoSolutionSpringApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.h2.tools.Server' defined in file [/opt/pentaho-biplatform-ce-6.1.0.1-196/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/GettingStartedDB-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "H2 TCP Server (tcp://localhost:9092)" (port may be in use), cause: "timeout" [90061-131]
```

Error is very clear - port 9092 is used by something else. The problem is that it is actually used by Pentaho, so it's complaining about the port which is currently used by itself...

To test that I've changed the port to 9093 in the following file:

```
./pentaho-solutions/system/GettingStartedDB.properties
```

The only difference between exceptions now was that port, which was 9093 this time, so it's definitely complaining about the port it is using, very weird.

Full log can be found here: http://ix.io/1ydv

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the following attribute to the **CATALINA_OPTS** options in the *start_pentaho.sh* file :

CATALINA_OPTS="... **-Dh2.bindAddress=*ip_of_your_machine*"**

It helped me to remove the *Exception opening port "H2 TCP Server (tcp://localhost:9092)" (port may be in use)* error.

Answer (score 3):

adding as follows in CATALINA_OPTS options in the start_pentaho.sh file is solving this issue:

CATALINA_OPTS="... -Dh2.bindAddress=localhost"

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that your server's `hostname` does not points to 127.0.0.1
Just add(edit) this line into your `/etc/hosts`:

`127.0.0.1  localhost YOUR_HOST_NAME`

Comment: The root cause I think is that Pentaho expects that my server's hostname must point to 127.0.0.1 :-)